# Smart Contract runs 1-2 times then runs out of gas afterwards

Tags: solidity, contract-development, remix, gas

I am creating a smart contract that will mint new trading card NFTs, for some reason the minting contract can only run 1-2 times before encountering (what I presume is) a runtime error and using up all its gas. I really don't know where I am going wrong, this is the first smart contract I have made.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity >= 0.8.2 < 0.9.0;

import "./CardPacking.sol";

contract CardGenerator is CardPacking{
    
    mapping (uint => address) cardIdToOwner; 
    mapping (address => uint) ownerCardCount;

    function canCardsBeMade() internal view returns (bool) {

        if (cards.length >= 99999999) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    function randomCardIdGenerator() internal view returns (uint) {

        uint rand = (block.timestamp + cards.length) % cardModulus;  // creates random uint of a selected length - this is vulnerable to attack, need randomizer oracle
        return rand;

    }

    function doesCardExist(uint _cardNum) internal view returns (bool){

        for (uint i; i < cards.length; i++){

            if (cards[i] >> 216 == _cardNum){
                return true;
            }

        }

        return false;
    }

    function uniqueCardGenerator() internal view returns (uint randNum){
        bool cardCreated = false;

        while (cardCreated == false) {

            randNum = randomCardIdGenerator();

            if (doesCardExist(randNum) == true){
                continue;
            } else {
                cardCreated = true;
            }
        }        
    }

    function createCard() external payable {

        require(msg.value == 10000 wei); // $1 gets you 5 cards, roughly

        uint cardNum = uniqueCardGenerator();
        cards.push(generateCardUint(cardNum, msg.sender, uint48(block.timestamp),1));
    
        uint id = cards.length - 1; // push generated card onto card list
        cardIdToOwner[id] = msg.sender;   // generated card belongs to function caller
        ownerCardCount[msg.sender]++;        
    }
}
```

Any variable names that are undefined, such as cardModulus, are in the CardPacking contract I imported from. All of my functions run properly independently, but all have an "infinite gas" warning. Cards are packed uints which unpack into an address and a unique, 1 in 99,999,999 card id.

This is CardPacking.sol:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity >=0.8.2.0;

contract CardPacking {

    uint internal counter = 0;
    uint internal immutable cardModulus = 10 ^ 8;

    uint[] public cards; // cards are stored as uints on a public array. Card attributes are found after using the generateCardStruct() function. 


    struct Card{

        address owner; // 160 bits
        uint48 timeOfCreation; // 48 bits
        uint8 cardCaptureMethod;
        uint cardNum; // log(2) 99999999 = 26.5, meaning we need 27 bits
        
    }

    function generateCardUint(uint _cardNum, address _owner, uint48 _timeOfCreation, uint8 _cardCaptureMethod) internal pure returns (uint256) {

        // @notice Creates uint that uses bitwise operations to pack in the card struct attributes.
        // @dev Bits 1-160 signify owner address, 161-208 the time of creation, 209-216 the way the card was obtained, and the remaining bits the card number.

        uint cardUint = uint256(uint160(_owner));
        cardUint |= (uint256(_timeOfCreation) << 160);
        cardUint |= (uint256(_cardCaptureMethod) << 208);
        cardUint |= (uint256(_cardNum) << 216);
       
        return cardUint;

    }

    function generateCardStruct(uint _cardId) internal view returns (Card memory) {

        Card memory _cardGenerated;

        _cardGenerated.owner = address(uint160(cards[_cardId] << 96));
        _cardGenerated.timeOfCreation = uint48(cards[_cardId] >> 160);
        _cardGenerated.cardCaptureMethod = uint8(cards[_cardId] >> 208);
        _cardGenerated.cardNum = uint256(cards[_cardId] >> 216);

        return _cardGenerated;
    }


}
```

Comment: Can you add the contents of CardPacking.sol? what is the value of cardModulus?
The problem may be an infinite loop in uniqueCardGenerator(), because randomCardIdGenerator() is not randomizing correctly

Comment: @ceseshi CardPacking is on the main post now, it has the value of cardModulus

Answer (score 0):

You are using a while loop, I would be wary of something like this causing you to run out of gas as it could get expensive very quickly and hit the gas limit easily. Consider running these checks off chain, and add a require to see if the generated id is already created when attempting to mint.

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in the declaration of cardModulus: 10 ^ 8 equals 2, change it to cardModulus = 10 ** 8 and it should work.

Bitwise Operators https://solidity-by-example.org/bitwise/